# Laravel Collections. Is there some kind of assertStructure method?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.5, laravel-collection

I'm writing tests and I want to assert, that a returned collection has some specific structure.

For asserting `json`s I'm using `assertJsonStructure()` method on the `Responce` object.

I have not found similar for the `\Illuminate\Support\Collection`. Did I miss some package/framework method.

*An example of what do I want*

```
$collection = collect([
    'name'      => 'John',
    'surname'   => 'Smith',
    'birthoday' => [
        'day'   => 23,
        'month' => 5,
        'year'  => 1970,
    ],
]);

$collection->assertStructure([          //true
    'name',
    'surname',
    'birthday' => ['day', 'month', 'year'],
]);
```

I will accept

> no

as an answer too, but if it is with an example of how to validate such a nested collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function on Collection instance, the closest you can do are:

- check if it has a key with `has()`
- Check if it contains some value with `contains()`
- There are other methods to check if something exist but

If you need inspiration, you can get it with the way Laravel implements `assertJsonStructure()` in `/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php`:

```
/**
 * Assert that the response has a given JSON structure.
 *
 * @param  array|null  $structure
 * @param  array|null  $responseData
 * @return $this
 */
public function assertJsonStructure(array $structure = null, $responseData = null)
{
    if (is_null($structure)) {
        return $this->assertJson($this->json());
    }

    if (is_null($responseData)) {
        $responseData = $this->decodeResponseJson();
    }

    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && $key === '*') {
            PHPUnit::assertInternalType('array', $responseData);

            foreach ($responseData as $responseDataItem) {
                $this->assertJsonStructure($structure['*'], $responseDataItem);
            }
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($key, $responseData);

            $this->assertJsonStructure($structure[$key], $responseData[$key]);
        } else {
            PHPUnit::assertArrayHasKey($value, $responseData);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see there is a recursive calls to check the structure in case there is sub-structure.

**UPDATE:**

As a basic test to solve your question, I modified the `assertJsonStructure()` to have `assertArrayStructure()` and this working test:

```
/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $collect = collect(['name' => '1', 'detail' => ['age' => 1,'class' => 'abc']]);

    $this->assertArrayStructure(['name', 'detail' => ['class', 'age']], $collect->toArray());
}


/**
 * Assert the array has a given structure.
 *
 * @param  array  $structure
 * @param  array  $arrayData
 * @return $this
 */
public function assertArrayStructure(array $structure, array $arrayData)
{
    foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && $key === '*') {
            $this->assertInternalType('array', $arrayData);

            foreach ($arrayData as $arrayDataItem) {
                $this->assertArrayStructure($structure['*'], $arrayDataItem);
            }
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $arrayData);

            $this->assertArrayStructure($structure[$key], $arrayData[$key]);
        } else {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($value, $arrayData);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, looks like it's the best and only option for now. Looks like I have a suggestion for Taylor)

Comment: @D.R. That'll be a good idea. However, I attempted to modify that `assertJsonStructure()` to use array instead. I will update the answer to possible solution - in case you need it urgently,

Comment: @D.R. I have included the solution, just in case you or anyone would find it useful.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I've already done with `phpUnit` `assertArraySubset()` method)

Comment: I'll check your option and will update you, if it works.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **no**, you can simply look for assertive laravel methods at the [API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/), there is no method at the namespace `Illuminate\Support\Collection` which makes what you are looking for. (You can find Laravel assertive method [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.html))

As a viable alternative, why you don't just serialize your collection and check it with the `assertJsonStructure()` method?

You could use the `response()` helper to populate a `Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse`:

```
use Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse;

$testResponse = new TestResponse(response()->json($collection->toArray());
return $testResponse->assertJsonStructure([
    'name',
    'surname',
    'birthday' => ['day', 'month', 'year'],
]);
```

How I came to this solution:

- You need the exact same object that returns the method `$this->json()` in a test, which comes from the trait `MakesHttpRequests` right [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L283).
- As the method comment specifies, it returns a `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse`.
- Look for the constructor [at the docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.html#method___construct) and see what it needs, a generic response object, `Illuminate/Http/Response`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @D.R. You are right, sorry, you need a response object, my bad!

Comment: Yes, I thought so and checked. It gives `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::assertJsonStructure()` :)

Comment: @D.R. I'm pretty strong headed, I think that this update could work :D

Comment: I still think it's quite an overhead, but I've voted for your question) Thank you. I'm sure somebody will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 8.x, the other answers are somewhat outdated. You can use `AssertableJsonString` as `TestResponse` uses that under the hood:

```php
(new \Illuminate\Testing\AssertableJsonString($yourJson))->assertStructure($yourStructure);
```